# Degenerate primer designing software

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, bioinformatics, molecular-genetics

Can any one provide online free degenerate primer designing software. I have tried couple of them like CODEHOP is one where BLOCK formatting step finding difficulty, can anyone help me out....

Comment: Benchling is a lab notebook with full DNA tools suite. You can check out a tutorial for the primer design tool her: https://benchling.com/tutorials/25/creating-and-analyzing-primers It's totally free to use for academics, and you can sign up via: https://benchling.com